# Send ftp file to Google Cloud debian 9

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ftp, debian

Im trying to send a file to google cloud using:

```
ftp -inv $HOSTFTP << EOF
user $USERFTP $PASSFTP
binary
get file.zip
bye
EOF
```

I configure:

```
 Host xx.xxx.xxx
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

But when i try to use ftp in Google cloud, always connection lost!
Anothers servers is working..
What is wrong?
Im thinking about some block from google cloud virtual machine.

Comment: FTP does not use `StrictHostKeyChecking`. Are you confusing `FTP` with `SFTP`? To use FTP you will need to configure an FTP server in your instance. `SCP` is built into the Google Cloud CLI: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp

Comment: This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCP there's a built in concept of [Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).

By default any new VM has a limited number of ports open (like 80 and 443) - ensure that the machine has port 21 and 22 are allowed by the firewall rules.

Comment: sshpass -p $PASSFTP sftp -P $PORTAFTP $USERFTP@$HOSTFTP << ENDSHERE
get file.zip
quit
ENDSHERE
"sftp works"